# SharePoint 2013 development environment

Tags: 2010, 2013, visual-studio-2013, development-enviroment, edition

I'm a new SharePoint developer and I required the following key information:-

1)      Development Environment:-

Scenario: In case of multiple developers working on separate projects of SharePoint 2013 development:-

i.            Do we require Separate machines (VM with Windows Server 2008 R2) for each developer with individual Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server and SharePoint Server 2013 ?

ii.            OR Each developer with Individual Visual Studio 2013 (local) can access the centralized SharePoint Server 2013 (VM with Windows Server 2008 R2) remotely ?

2)      Visual Studio Version:-

Which edition (Professional OR Premium OR Ultimate) of Visual Studio 2013 IDE is well suited to perform extensive development activity with SharePoint 2013 ?

3)      SharePoint 2010 Development:-

Is it possible to perform development for SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2013 IDE ?

Thanks in Advance.